# Как определить на каком индексе (длине) находится символ?

Tags: c#

Как определить на какой длине находится нужная мне строка от пользователя?
Например, чтобы пользователь ввёл My name *is* Alex. Как мне определить на каком индексе находится слово *is*
Это к примеру, как мне вытащить слово *is* из текста?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `IndexOf` класса `string`. Он возвращает индекс итересующей вас подстроки. Например:

```
int index = "My name is Alex".IndexOf("is"); // вернёт 8
```

В случае, если подстрока не найдена, метод вернёт -1. [Пример](http://ideone.com/Ft7AgA)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я хочу вывести строку с помощью Substring, а как определить длину строки с начинающейся подстроки? Например, метод вернул 8, но как определить, до какого индекса нужно прочесть строку, чтобы он вывел is? Это мне нужно для Substring'a

Comment: @Emmanuel добавьте к полученному индексу длину искомой строки.

Comment: Спасибо большое!